View Transition on scrollable list view leaks
Reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/HuakunShen/view-transition-leak-demo
I am using view transition API to do fade animation for page transition and it works fine.
Then I used view transition to transition an image between two pages, from a list view to a detail view.
But the items scrolled out of view show up during page transition.
Here are some screenshots, when clicked on the last item, the logo should transition to the logo position in the next page.


During transition, the search bar fade out and the logo images of the out-of-view list items show up.
See the green box

Here is a screenshot from the demo

